# Firefox SVG transform-origin still not fixed?

Tags: javascript, firefox, svg, css-transforms

I read in the Firefox documentation that SVG transform-origin was fixed in Firefox with Firefox 41+, but I'm using Firefox 49 and having some weird effects..

Here is my SVG animation in Chrome:

[image: correct animation]

.. and here it is in Firefox:

[image: wtf firefox]

My code is like so—

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 960.59 674.02">
  ...
  <path class="fillCup" d="M395.56,528.9l6.53,36.05c0,2.42,6.08,4.38,13.57,4.38s13.57-2,13.57-4.38l6.53-36.05s-0.68,4.5-20.11,4.5S395.56,528.9,395.56,528.9Z" transform="translate(-17.93 -12.21)"/>
  <polygon class="sparkle" points="407.41 538.79 407.47 530.6 403.98 528.96 407.82 528.62 410.59 520.9 410.53 529.1 413.81 530.7 410.18 531.08 407.41 538.79"/>
</svg>
```

and the css:

```
.sparkle {
  fill: #fff;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  animation: pulse 1s linear 0s infinite alternate forwards;
}

.fillCup {
  fill: #4fc3f7;
  transform: scale(0, 0) translate(-17.93px, -12.21px);
  transform-origin: 10% 70%;
}
```

where animation `pulse` is

```
@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    transform: scale(.7, .7);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1, 1);
  }
}
```

and the `.fillCup` polygon is being animated to `scale(1, 1)` with javascript.

(**note:** I'm actually using a sass mixin for these, but I've ommitted them for simplification of code. firefox chooses to use `transform` over `moz-transform` or `-webkit-transform` so that's the only "prefix" I've included here.)

Is there a "proper" way I'm supposed to be doing the `transform-origin` so that it works across all browsers? Is Chrome the one that's doing it incorrectly? When I switch the percentages in Firefox the actual positions it uses seem completely arbitrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox is actually the one following the specification correctly.  It is Chrome that is incorrect.  It implemented `transform-origin` early and the behaviour of percentage values is different from that finalised in the spec.

The simplest solution is to not use percentage values.  Use absolute coordinates.

Comment: Would absolute coordinates work when scaling the SVG? Also, what are the absolute coordinates relative to? The SVG box as a whole? Thanks!

Comment: (1) Yes they should (2) they have the same coordinate space as the element it is being applied to.